# android mobile to mobile file transfer

Tags: java, android

Although it seems like a simple problem, I have really come up empty on Google.  I want to take a 3gp file on one device's SD card and transfer it over WIFI to another device.  Really not sure how to do this, I would appreciate if someone could provide me some references or code snippets.  Do I really have to do this at the FileOutputStream / socket level?

Comment: Over the network? Email, MMS, bytestream? Over bluetooth? *How* do you want to transfer the file? Via a server or directly between devices?

Comment: Ah sorry, over wifi.  Question edited.

Comment: And the sender has the IP of the receiving device?

Comment: Posted an answer. I believe the cleanest solution is to do it with channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any API for transferring files specific to Android which is not available in Java, so my best bet would be to google for an arbitrary Java-solution.

You may want to have a look at the NIO package and the `FileChannel`. Specifically the `transferTo` and `transferFrom` methods.

- [Writing to a SocketChannel](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/WriteSocket.html)
- [Reading from a SocketChannel](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/ReadSocket.html)

Comment: Well after a lot of searching you seem to be correct :P  The only way to do the deed is at this level.